# How to get the selected Row values in TextBoxes for DataGrid in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I want to display a selected row out of the datagrid into some textboxes. The problem is that it becomes null at line 4 when converting into a DataRowView. Why is this?

```
1 private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
2    {
3        DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
4        DataRowView selected_row = grid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
5
6        if (selected_row != null)
7        {
8            comboBoxCategory.Text = selected_row["Category"].ToString();
9            textBoxBrand.Text = selected_row["Brand"].ToString();
10            textBoxName.Text = selected_row["Name"].ToString();
11            textBoxCount.Text = selected_row["Count"].ToString();
12            textBoxPrice.Text = selected_row["Price"].ToString();
13       }
14    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: appreciate you have put line number with the code :clap

Comment: Are you utilizing mvvm, how are you filling the datagrid?

Comment: Can you please try `SelectedRows` and then `SelectedRows[index]` for the respective column

Comment: I think it's just a DataRow and not the whole DataRowView

Comment: Your DataGrid items isn't of type `DataRowView`, so `as` cast returns `null`. Most likely it is some Model class object (with `ID`, `Categorie` etc properties). You can check `grid.SelectedItem` type with `GetType` method in debug mode: https://i.ibb.co/KwLb7tJ/1.jpg. And then use correct cast with `as`.

Comment: @Futurex: How do you set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly the `SelectedItem` property doesn't return a `DataRowView`.

Either cast to the appropriate type assuming you have define one, or use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    dynamic selected_row = grid.SelectedItem;

    comboBoxCategory.Text = selected_row.Categorie.ToString();
    textBoxBrand.Text = selected_row.Merk.ToString();
    textBoxName.Text = selected_row.Naam.ToString();
    textBoxCount.Text = selected_row.Aantal.ToString();
    textBoxPrice.Text = selected_row.Prijs.ToString();
}
```